# Fold expression with comma operator and variadic template parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, operator-keyword, fold

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename ...Args>
void output_argus(Args&&... args) 
{
    ((cout << args << '\n'), ...);    // #1
    (... , (cout << args << '\n'));   // #2
}


int main()
{
    output_argus(1, "test", 5.6f);
}
```

Based on c++ operator [doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `','` is a **left to right operator**. It is meaning `a, b, c, d` meaning `(((a, b), c),d)` not `(a, (b, (c, d)))`. This is important if a, b, c, d are statements.

However, based on fold expression [doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), for `','` which should use **unary left fold**.

My question why both statements in my code are working? Shouldn't only #2 work?
And also how to understand `...` and `args`. and nested fold expression?

Comment: I dont understand how `(((a, b), c),d)` and `(a, (b, (c, d)))` are different... the first element is evaluated then discarded... so any way do you do it `a` will be  evaluated then discarded, `b` will be evaluated then discarded, `c` will be evaluated then discarded, ...

Comment: Left and right fold often do the same thing, despite seeming opposite.

Comment: `(((a, b), c),d)` is exactly the same as `(a, (b, (c, d)))`. The sequencing is a -> b -> c -> d, and the result is `d`. Actually this might be a good example to understand for people unsure about the difference between precedence and order of evaluation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's say we're folding 3 expressions over a binary operator, with a unary fold. We have two options here: `(xs @ ...)` (a unary right fold) and `(... @ xs)` (a unary left fold).

`(xs @ ...)` expands out to `(a @ (b @ c))`

`(... @ xs)` expands out to `((a @ b) @ c)`

What can we say about the difference between the expressions `a @ (b @ c)` and `(a @ b) @ c`? If `@` is **associative** over these types, then those two expressions are identical. That's what associative means. If you had a parameter pack of integers, then a unary left fold over `+` and a unary right fold over `+` will have the same value (modulo overflow), because addition is associative. Subtraction, on the other hand, is not associative. `(xs - ...)` and `(... - xs)` mean very different things.

Likewise, the `,` operator in C++ is associative. It doesn't matter which way you parenthesize the expressions. `((a, b), c)` and `(a, (b, c))` both evaluate and discard `a`, then evaluate and discard `b`, then evaluate `c` and that's the result. It's easier to see if you reduce the expressions to just letters why this is the case.

As a result, both `((cout << args << '\n'), ...)` and `(... , (cout << args << '\n'))` do the same thing, and they both effectively mean:

```
cout << args1 << '\n';
cout << args2 << '\n';
// ...
cout << argsN << '\n';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It gives me new thinking about comma and parentheses.  It turns out a @ (b @ c) won't lead to execute b first which is true in cpp and false in mathematic field. The doc's academic style makes me feel it's expand in a logic way.

Comment: @KeZhang, It shouldn't matter which of a/b/c you evaluate ("execute") first in math. The parentheses affect the precedence, which means you need to calculate `b @ c` before calculating `a @ (b @ c)`, but that's also true of C++. Unlike C++, math doesn't have things with side effects like prints, and that's where C++ needs to consider evaluation order beyond simple precedence and associativity rules.

Comment: @chris , about **which means you need to calculate b @ c before calculating a @ (b @ c)**, I have different opinion and I post a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53346105/comma-operator-with-parentheses-order?noredirect=1#comment93571067_53346105).

Comment: @KeZhang, Keep in mind when I say `b @ c` needs to be done before `a @ (b @ c)`, that doesn't impose any restrictions on `a`, `b`, and `c` individually. You could evaluate `a`, then `b`, then `c`, then the inner `@`, then the outer `@`. What I meant was that you cannot, for example, evaluate the outer `@` before the inner one because the outer one depends on the result of the inner one. Likewise, you can't evaluate the inner `@` before evaluating `b` and `c` because it depends on those. Apart from dependencies, the order is free reign unless otherwise specified, like the comma operator is.

Answer (score 5):

From the linked page, your #1 expands as follows:

```
((cout << args₀ << '\n'), ((cout << args₁ << '\n'), (cout << args₂ << '\n')));
```

Removing some repetition to make it cleaner:

```
args₀, (args₁, args₂)
```

For #2, the expansion boils down to:

```
(args₀, args₁), args₂
```

Let's walk through the evaluation of each one.

#1:

```
args₀  ,  (args₁, args₂)
      ^^^
```

The underlined comma evaluates the left side, printing `1`. Then the right side is evaluated, which evaluates the print of `args₁`, printing `test`, then the print of `args₂`, printing `5.6`.

#2:

```
(args₀, args₁)  ,  args₂
               ^^^
```

The underlined comma evaluates the left side. This triggers evaluation of the other comma, which evaluates the print of `args₀`, printing `1`, then evaluates the print of `args₁`, printing `test`. Now the underlined comma is done evaluating the left side and evaluates the right side, printing `5.6`.

As you can see, both produce the same evaluation order of each individual argument despite the grouping of parentheses being different.

Note that in general, this might not always hold. Some operators, such as `+`, do not have a guaranteed evaluation order like the comma operator does. Were such an operator used instead of the comma to join the print expressions, the compiler could ultimately choose to evaluate the individual argument prints in any order.

Comment: Streaming with cout may be a better example of difference.  `(cout << 1)<<2` vs `cout <<(1 << 2)`.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, While true, I couldn't think of a particularly nice way to fit it in with fold expression explanations. The two options provided are `(cout << 1) << 2` and `1 << (2 << cout)`, with the need to do some kind of extra building on top if we want to form `cout << (1 << 2)` for an example. I guess `cout` could be part of the parameter pack to make it work, though, instead of needing the binary fold.