# Which C++ fold idiom is preferred, short circuit comma or nested lambda?

Tags: c++, c++20, fold-expression

First option technically has less cognitive load because you don't need to be concerned with `||` or `,` operators. It is unfortunate that two nested lambdas are required to first get `Is`, and then to fold on the inner lambda. See [cppreference fold expression examples](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) and [StackOverflow fold over pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62248302/lambda-fold-expression-get-index).

```
// option 1
template<size_t N, typename... Ts> using nth =
    typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type;

template <typename... Ts>
class type_list {
    // ...
public:
    template <typename T>
    constexpr auto locate()
    {
        std::size_t idx{sizeof...(Ts)};
        [&idx]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
            ([&idx]() {
                if (std::is_same_v<T, nth<Is, Ts...>>) {
                    idx = Is;
                }
            }(), ...);
        } (std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{});
        return idx;
    }
};
```

Second option is shorter and benefits from short circuit evaluation. It feels easier to read - but perhaps deceptively, because the mechanism itself is more complicated. See [DevTut fold over comma](https://devtut.github.io/cpp/fold-expressions.html) and [StackOverflow fold over comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53330713/fold-expression-with-comma-operator-and-variadic-template-parameter-pack).

```
// option 2
template <typename... Ts>
class type_list {
    // ...
public:
    template <typename T>
    constexpr auto locate() {
        return [] <std::size_t... Is> (std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
            std::size_t idx{sizeof...(Ts)};
            ((idx = Is, std::is_same_v<T, Ts>) || ...);
            return idx;
        } (std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{});
    }
};
```

In C++26, we will hopefully get `for...` and until then, what is considered more idiomatic?

Okay, maybe "idiomatic" isn't the right word. Which of these compile time compatible looping structures is least offensive, in place of first class language support for parameter packs and folding on control flow, to perform basic variadic template metaprogramming in C++20?

Comment: `sizeof...(Ts)` Where is `Ts` coming from?

Comment: @NicolBolas from the containing class definition, `locate` is a method

Comment: This doesn't compile. `Is` cannot be inferred.

Comment: @PasserBy https://godbolt.org/z/TeKPq69rn the first one does not compile with an inferred arg, the second one does. no idea why..

Comment: It compiled with the wrong results.

Comment: @PasserBy yes, you are correct, compiler can't infer the argument. fixed: https://godbolt.org/z/EvsY6h5T3